# Angular - share component among children

Tags: angular

```
// APP structure
app (/)
  admin (/admin, this will redirect to /admin/dashboard)
    dashboard (/admin/dashboard)
    users (/admin/users)
```

```
// app.component.html

<div>
    <app-logo/>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

```
// app-routing.module.ts

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "admin",
        loadChildren: () => import("./admin/routing.module").then(m => m.AdminRoutingModule),
    },
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

We see that in `app.component.html` if we add a `Logo` component it will render in every page. Now I have a route `admin` with some sub routes:

```
// admin-routing.module.ts
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "dashboard",
        loadChildren: () => import("./dashboard/dashboard.module").then(m => m.AdminDashboardModule),
    },
    {
        path: "",
        redirectTo: 'dashboard',
        pathMatch: 'full',
    },
    {
        path: "users",
        loadChildren: () => import("./users/users.module").then(m => m.AdminUsersModule),
    },
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AdminRoutingModule {
}
```

In the `admin.component.html` I add another component `Sidebar`:

```
// admin.component.html
<app-sidebar/>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I expect to see the sidebar in every page of `/admin/dashboard` and `/admin/users/` but nothing is rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hard to be sure without seeing relevant portion of app routing module, but you probably need something like:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
      path: '',
      component: AdminComponent,
      children: [
        {
          path: "dashboard",
          loadChildren: () => import("./dashboard/dashboard.module").then(m => m.AdminDashboardModule),
        },
        {
          path: "",
          redirectTo: 'dashboard',
          pathMatch: 'full',
        },
        {
          path: "users",
          loadChildren: () => import("./users/users.module").then(m => m.AdminUsersModule),
        },
      ];
   }
]
```

so that you're actually using the `AdminComponent` to wrap the admin routes.